# Contact form 7 is sending an unwanted autoresponse

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

We have a contact form 7 form on our site but for some reason it is sending out an unwanted auto response when filled. The response is not set up under mail 2. I am thinking that at one point there was a third party page created to send a response but I am not sure how to trace it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Welcome to the WordPress Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, questions regarding 3rd party plugins ( such as Contact Form 7 ) are considered to be [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Please [take the tour](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about how this website works. A better place to ask this type of question would be on the [plugins support forums](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/contact-form-7).